# Applications of Koszul's formula other than the fundamental lemma of Riemannian geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ho.history-overview

I'm wondering what else one can do with Koszul's formula

$$2\langle\nabla_XA,B\rangle = X\langle A,B\rangle-B\langle X,A\rangle + A\langle X,B\rangle - \langle A,[X,B]\rangle + \langle[B,X],A\rangle - \langle B,[A,X]\rangle$$

beyond proving existence and uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection. I haven't yet seen anybody using it for anything else, which would be quite curious.

Here's a pretty and simple example. I don't know if it is known...

Let $\nabla^{LC}$ be the Levi-Civita connection and $\nabla$ be some other metric connection with torsion $T$. Then

$$2\langle\nabla_XA,B\rangle - 2\langle\nabla_X^{LC}A,B\rangle= \langle T(A,X),B\rangle -\langle T(A,B),X\rangle - \langle T(B,X),A\rangle$$

An application of this would be to compute the LC-connection for the metric $\langle K\cdot,K\cdot\rangle$ in terms of the endomorphism $K$ and the LC-connection for $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$. The computation starts with the connection $K^{-1}\nabla^{LC} K$, which is metric for $\langle K\cdot,K\cdot\rangle$...

I can't guarantee correct letters and signs :-)

Comment: Riemannian geometry IS the study of the Levi-Civita connection and the Koszul formula is an explicit expression for the connection.  So ultimately anything you do in Riemannian geometry is bound to be using it at some level.  If, on the other hand, you mean what other formulae you can get by formally manipulating the Koszul formula, then there are plenty, but I would not necessarily call them "applications".  Killing's equation comes to mind, as well as the O'Neill formulae for submersions, the basic formulae for homogeneous geometry,...  Pick any book on differential geometry: e.g., do Carmo.

Comment: Indeed. Except when the glory breaks down and coordinates get introduced (or used implicitly). (If not, wait till play with Laplacians begins and frames introduced...) BTW, one application of my application would be the coordinate representation of the LC connection.

PLEASE NOTE: I'm far away from the library and made it there only a few times this century - and it was open a few of these occasions. But I've seen and possibly remember quite a few of these books, e.g. none on Ricci flow without ungeometricly resorting to coordinate stuff when things get most basic

Comment: So let me get this straight: you make a distinction between the Koszul formula and the formula for the Christoffel symbols?  I don't think there is any conceptual difference between the two.  I suppose it's a question of how much pain are you willing to endure in order to keep everything coordinate-free.  Analysts as a general rule seem to have a low pain threshold :)

Comment: Hm, yes I'm actually trying to avoid pain. I might perhaps have an infinitude of indices (symbolic or not) or try to keep track of the tensor product rule (after all, it's tensor calculus) and not get lost (or waste sparse IQ) in the debauch of indices. Why else Koszul connections? Of course Christoffel stuff and Koszul covariant derivatives (plus Cartan's calculus, Penrose spaghetti, etc. pp.) are all about the same thing, but at least there should be some motivation to stay in one concept (plus, avoid coordinates (it could be a ringed space) (or the coordinates being unknown or irrelevant)).

Comment: Anything proved using local co-ordinates in Riemannian geometry can be proved without using local co-ordinates and vice versa. It's usually a matter of habit and/or taste. Some of us find it advantageous to know how to prove almost anything at least three different ways (using co-ordinates, an arbitrary frame of vector fields, or using differential forms and Cartan's moving frame approach).

Comment: José, I guess you mean by Killing's equation Pepeter Petersen, Riem. Geom. 2nd ed, Proposition 27? Yeah, I should have had a 2nd look in this book, having also O'Neill and Mixed Curvature Equations with Koszul (KF). - Excuse given to Deane below --- I almost bet Petersen's Proposition 28 could also be proved with KF, showing that $f\mapsto\nabla_V(fX)$ is tensorial if $X\vert_p=0 and $\nablaX\vert_p$. So his proof would be a "bad" example for my funny conjecture that <i>anything you can derive from a KF</i> can also be derived without Lie brackets. Yeah the paradox - but now I go sleep...


Comment: My latest speculatory argument turned out to be complete nonsense... But still methinks I smell something with Killing fields. The Petersen Koszul formula says the covariant derivative of a Killing 1-form-from-field is the exterior differential. (So the point seems more: Koszul's formula has nothing to say on Killing fields because it gives essentially zero.) Thru the lens of my calculus I see Bianchi identity symmetries lurking behind covariant differentiation of Killing fields. 

Comment: Martin, I don't believe that the Bianchi identities arise from Killing fields, because in general there are not enough Killing fields to generate the identities. I believe instead that the Bianchi identities arise from the action of arbitrary diffeomorphisms or infinitesimal diffeormorphisms (i.e., vector fields) on the curvature tensor. I used to know the details, but I can't remember them offhand.

Comment: Deane, of course I don't think they arise from Killing fields. I haven't yet done the math (currently hard at work with other stuff), but methinks from the 1st Bianchi identity for curvature applied to Killing field I can just drop the antisymmetrisator and get a cyclic symmetry for the 2nd covariant derivative of the Killing field. -- Your favorite approach to Bianchi is Kazdan's "another proof". My way I get them by total tensor product rules and a crucial property of the "cyclator", and they look like in Cartan calculus (incl. torsion).

Comment: The derivation of the Bianchi identities only using the diffeomorphism invariance of curvature can be found in "the ricci flow : an introduction", by Chow and Knopf.


Comment: Quite a borderline comment but I find it funny. There is (at least) one thing I don't know how to prove without coordinates. Whena metric evolves by the Ricci flow, the evolution of the curvature operator is given by : $\partial_t R=\Delta R + R^2+R^# $, where $R^#$ can be defined in a coordinate free way using the Lie algebra structure of $\Lambda^2 TM $. 

A substantial part of the proof can be done without coordinates (as in Toppong lectures) but I never saw anyone that goes from the expression ypu found in Topping book to the Lie algebraic expression without coordinates.

Comment: Thomas, I took a quick glance at Topping's notes and did not see anything that could not be proved in a co-ordinate-free fashion. Could you point me to which part of Topping's proof you are referring to? (I'm looking at the PDF version Topping has made available for download).

Answer (score 3):

Koszul's formula simply expresses the Levi-Civita connection explicitly in terms of the Riemannian metric. It is quite useful any time you want to eliminate the connection from a formula and write the formula in terms of the metric only. José cited some nice examples. I haven't checked, but I bet the book by Cheeger and Ebin discusses these examples and maybe  more quite explicitly.

But it is no different from writing a formula in local co-ordinates and replacing all appearances of Christoffel symbols by their formula in terms of partial derivatives of the Riemannian metric. This is often an equally useful thing to do when, for example, you want to apply PDE techniques or theorems that are stated in terms of co-ordinates to a problem in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Deane, 1) my example even involves 2 connections...
2a) I find it disadvantageous to have to learn at least 3 calculi for the whole picture. 2b) I found me developing my own calculus to sanely get into Hilbert space via Stokes theorem (for doing geometric PDE geometrically, like Bochner theorems)



Indeed José has an excellent answer. There's sure much more. Alas I had to suffer through O'Neill's formulae etc. in Christoffelian (by a famous German differential ring theorist, no less).

Comment: Martin, I also prefer to understand everything from a single approach. And to some extent I have succeeded in developing a single way to do everything I need to do in Riemannian geometry. But it appears that each of us ends up developing our own preferred approach and even notation. But even then my approach does not accomplish absolutely everything I want, just most of it. Depending on the context, I still sometimes find either the differential form or local co-ordinate approach the easiest way to do what I want. So I find it quite handy to be able to use them, too.

Comment: P.S.: Said German differential ring theorist's lectures had at least a complete proof of the fundamental lemma of Riem. Geom., completely proving tensoriality on the r.h.s.

P.P.S.: My answer-comment to Jose is hidden (anyhow syntacticly mangled) - Killing fields indeed serving an example of Koszul vs. not-Koszul.

P.P.P.S.: Something learned today. Thanks, sirs.

Comment: What's the "fundamental lemma of Riemannian geometry"?

Comment: Haha, good question. My few books call it the fundamental theorem: Existence and uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection. -- I have currently no idea why I called it lemma.

Comment: I didn't understand "tensorality on the rhs" bit. Presumably, you mean tensorial in $X$ and $B$ but not $A$. Also, I don't want to understate the importance of this formula, but "fundamental lemma" or "fundamental theorem" seems like an overstatement to me.

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps Levi-Civita theorem would be a better name. --- I will regard my question as answered when someone can tell something about my example application (is it known, where used, ...) (but forget about coordinates - deriving a coordinate formula that way is of course not the least painful way...)

Comment: Martin, do you know where connections with torsion are used? I've never used one in my life.

Comment: Me neither (but my math life is just a tiny fraction of yours) -- except: The K-transformed connection I mentioned in the question is a quite natural idea and it has torsion.

Comment: @Deane: Connections with torsion are popular in physics. They also arise naturally in pure geometry. If one considers Hermitian non-Kahler manifolds, then the Chern connection (compatible with the Hermitian metric and the complex structure) has torsion. In fact, its torsion vanishes if and only if the manifold is indeed Kahler. There is an analogous "Obata" connection in quaternionic geometry. When one has an additional structure on a Riemannian manifold (a special tensor, usually a form), then it is more natural to study connections which make that form parallel. Usually these have torsion.

Comment: I agree with Deanne, in principle *any* calculation can be done coordinate free, in local coordinates, or with moving frames. However, it is undeniable that for some results, one of these three methods might be much simpler than the others. For example, many of the evolution equations derived using local coordinates in Ricci flow or in mean curvature flow, ugly as they may be, would be even harder to prove coordinate-free. The fact that we can always choose local normal coordinates makes these computations much more manageable. I think all geometers should be comfortable with all 3 methods.

Comment: Spiro, thanks very much for your comments. It's been a long time since I've done Ricci flow (or, more generally, time-dependent metric) calculations, so I'm only slowly remembering where the difficulties are. The difficulty, as I recall, occurs because the connection itself varies with time and you have to account for this. I remember struggling with this and eventually figuring out how to do tensor calculus properly in this setting without having to resort to local co-ordinates.

Comment: Spiro, thanks also for explaining how connections with torsion arise naturally in some settings.

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried some of the calculations Deane mentioned. The "ugly" computations mentioned by Spiro seem indeed much easier in an appropriate coordinate free tensor calculus.

Answer (score 0):

I've meanwhile found out that my innocent example ...

**1.)** ... amounts to a rediscovery of Schouten's *[contorsion tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contorsion_tensor)*. (See e.g. [this note](http://www.telesio-galilei.com/tg/images/stories/documents/discussion/riemann%20cartan%20connection%20wa%20rodrigues%20jr%2027-11-2008.pdf)).

This concept is important in [torsion gravity](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0501017) (which isn't as exotic as it may sound - except for some [charlatanry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_field) derived from it...) My example equation seems to express the equivalence principle (cf. [link](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0501017) eq. (255)). See also Rodrigues & Oliveira: [The many faces of Maxwell, Dirac and Einstein equations](http://www.springer.com/physics/theoretical,+mathematical+%26+computational+physics/book/978-3-540-71292-3).

As I've already hinted here, contorsion stuff (or what I would term the *contorsion operator*) can also occur in computations with torsion-free connections.

**2.)** ... leads to a generalization of the fundamental "lemma", a.k.a. Levi-Civita theorem: *For any given vector-valued 2-form $T$ there exists a unique metric connection with torsion $T$*.